# Querystring in the URL without?

Tags: asp.net-core, url, .net-core, razor-pages

I am working with asp.net core razor pages. I remember a years ago working with MVC, I was able to redirect to a page with querystring without the question mark, but a slash instead.

http://www.exampletest.com/contact/mike@gmail.com

Now in with razor pages, the URL is back to looking like...

http://www.exampletext.com/contact?ID=mike@gmail.com

Is there a way to once again get the querystring with a slash instead of question mark, like before?

My code is as follows:

```
            <a asp-page="Index" asp-route-id="mike@gmail.com">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => stock.Symbol) 
            </a>
```

The Index.cshtml page is in the "contact" directory.

Comment: When we use `/` in the URL, it considers a path for the site. When you replace the `?` with `/` then it might not find the proper path to load the page and you might receive an error. Could you please explain the purpose, and why you want to replace the `?` in the URL for the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "querystring without the question mark" is known as [route data](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#route-data), with each item occupying a segment of the URL. Route data parameters are defined in a [route template](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#route-templates), which you pass to the `@page` directive in the Razor file itself.

Change the `@page` directive in the *Index.cshtml* to the following and it should all magically work:

```
@page "{id}"
```

Comment: Great! That worked. Does the template need to be defined in the cshtml page itself? I remember MVC had a separate file that had the routing template.

Comment: You could define the template using the AddPageRoute method in your Program/Startup class instead (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#friendly-routes), but I recommend defining it in the page and only useng the alternative approach to add additional route templates if you want your page to be found at different URLs.